# The given key was not present in the dictionary. error when adding a SumCalc

Tags: acumatica

I added a line user-defined field and a header user-defined field.  However, when I attempt to total the line value on the header, I receive "The given key was not present in the dictionary" when accessing the screen.  The screen is Sales Order Invoice (SO.30.10.00).  Below is the code for the header and line fields.

It appears there is both a SO.SOInvoice and AR.ARRegister objects, my guess is that I need to provide a declaration somehow for the extension object for AR.ARRegister, but not sure how to do that.

[Print Screen of DAC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2azkM.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve the issue.  To resolve the issue, I un-published the project and cleared my cache.  I then re-published the project and everything appears to be working correctly.